# Type mismatch in Scala(filter function)

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and try to focus on more functional programming
side of it.

I am trying to write a function filter.

Here is a definition and implementation:

```
def filter[A, B](f: A => Boolean, l: List[A]): List[B] = l match {
    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => if (f(x)) (x: B) :: filter(f, xs) else filter(f, xs)
}
```

Using this function, I get this error:
:32: error: type mismatch;

```
 found   : x.type (with underlying type A)
 required: B
           case x :: xs => if (f(x)) (x: B) :: filter(f, xs) else filter(f, xs)
```

Now, before that I wrote a function map:

```
def map[A, B](f: A => B, l: List[A]): List[B] = l match {
    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => f(x) :: map(f, xs)
}
```

that actually applies function f to convert each list element from type A to type B.

My error for filter seems to be caused by the fact that function taken by filter
does nothing to list element x of type A, so type checker thinks that I am still building a list of type A when B is required. You can see I tried to specify x as type B but it was in vain. Can anyone confirm that I understood problem correctly and how can I make x as type B? I could just return list of type A but
this is a function definition that is given as an exercise and I cannot change it.

Comment: `filter` doesn't convert the elements in the list, it just removes those for which the predicate returns `false`. You can just remove the type parameter `B` and change the return type to `List[A]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter method seems to try converting `A` to `B` which is not what filter methods usually do. `A` and `B` are two unrelated types, so you cannot cast between them

You would want something like that:

```
def filter[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] = l match {
    case Nil => List()
    case x :: xs => if (f(x)) x :: filter(xs)(f) else filter(xs)(f)
}
```

But you also can write this one a bit simpler:

```
def filter[A](l: List[A])(f: A => Boolean): List[A] =
    for (x <- l if f(x)) yield x
```

Please also notice that I have swapped the arguments and divided them. This is done in order for scala's type inference to infer `A` automatically. Now you can do this:

```
filter(List(1, 3, 5, 7))(_ > 4)
```

where `Int` type is infered implicitly

Comment: So, are you telling that method declaration is wrong since filtering just selects values from the list if it passes the test, i.e. if I host type A then it makes no sense that filter function retrieves me type B elements? I thought that since I do nothing to the list elements, then B becomes A, i.e. if I had List[Integer] then even if I had List[B] then B = Integer as well.

Comment: scala does not infer `B = A` in this case. Moreover it is not the case at all. Your filter can be called as `filter[Int, String]` which is completely correct. Afterall you can do this with `map`, why can't you do it with `filter`? Yes, if you look at `filter` in scala library it is more complicated (see `TraversableLike`). It returns `Repr` type, but not `TraversableLike`. This is done so anything that implements `TraversableLike` could still return self type if `filter` called. So `List` return `List` when `filter` is called, but not `TraversableLike`

Comment: Thank you, will check all of this out.